# French 10-year carte de séjour holder out of France for 4 years

Tags: residency, marriage, canadian-citizens, french-citizens

My husband is a 10-year carte de séjour holder and he visited Canada, met me and we decided to get married. He applied for permanent resident status here, which took rather long and he ended up staying here for 4 years. Now, he is a permanent resident of Canada.

Does that mean he lost his status in France? Does staying outside France for 4 years men he lost his status there?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The carte de séjour can be revoked when someone has left the French territory for 3 years. So yes, he would have lost his status.

It would have been possible for him to extend it, but it appears that he would have had to request it, probably before the 3 years had passed.

That said, it may be worth asking someone (e.g. at the Embassy) to confirm.

> Article L314-7
> Modifié par Loi n°2006-911 du 24 juillet 2006 - art. 28 JORF 25 juillet 2006
> La carte de résident d'un étranger qui a quitté le territoire français et a résidé à l'étranger pendant une période de plus de trois ans consécutifs est périmée, de même que la carte de résident portant la mention "résident de longue durée-CE" accordée par la France lorsque son titulaire a résidé en dehors du territoire des Etats membres de l'Union européenne pendant une période de plus de trois ans consécutifs.
>
> La période mentionnée ci-dessus peut être prolongée si l'intéressé en a fait la demande soit avant son départ de France, soit pendant son séjour à l'étranger.
>
> En outre, est périmée la carte de résident portant la mention "résident de longue durée-CE" accordée par la France lorsque son titulaire a, depuis sa délivrance, acquis ce statut dans un autre Etat membre de l'Union européenne, ou lorsqu'il a résidé en dehors du territoire national pendant une période de six ans consécutifs.